# Levene Test in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, anova

The results from three experiments with overlapping 95% confidence intervals are given below. The task is to confirm if the results for all three experiments are not significantly different. **The Assumption is that the 3 sample below are random, independent, parametric & normally distributed**

```
`Experiment1 = np.array([1.595440,1.419730,0.000000,0.000000])`
`Experiment2 = np.array([1.433800,2.079700,0.892139,2.384740])`
`Experiment3 = np.array([0.036930,0.938018,0.995956,1.006970])`
```

I would need help with performing Levene test on the data. Assistance would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I got your correct, the default center is median, you can also use mean:

```
from scipy.stats import levene
import numpy as np

Experiment1 = np.array([1.595440,1.419730,0.000000,0.000000])
Experiment2 = np.array([1.433800,2.079700,0.892139,2.384740])
Experiment3 = np.array([0.036930,0.938018,0.995956,1.006970])

levene(Experiment1 ,Experiment2,Experiment3)

LeveneResult(statistic=2.6741725711150446, pvalue=0.12259792666001798)
```